# How to find a single NaN row in my DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a 259399 rows and one column. It is called `hfreq`. In one single row I have a NaN value and I want to find it. I thought this is easy and tried `hfreq[hfreq.isnull()]`. But as you can see it doesn't help:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how is it done correctly?

**Edit:** For clarity: That is how my DataFrame looks like:

[image]

There is only one NaN value hidden somewhere in the middle and I want to learn where it is so I want to get its index.

Comment: @Topsail - that's 5 NaNs, not 1. The sum and the count is meant to demonstrate there is 1 NaN.

Comment: @topsail I added a screenshot of the actual DataFrame for clarity.

Comment: @tdelaney You understood me very well. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It would help to switch from images to pasted text in code blocks. The scale on those images is huge... at least on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code.

```
hfreq.loc[hfreq['value'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. The missing value was at `2007-08-20 17:00:00` in case you wanna know xD. Can you explain what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You have dataframe with a single column, not series. In order to find the missing value in a column, you have to access the column not dataframe. In addition, use loc or iloc for indexing.